# Why does my well pump pressure suddenly drop?

Tags: pump, well

I have a 1 1/2 HP submersible pump that I am having a problem with. The New pressure switch points will close at times and the pressure will start to pump and suddenly drop to 0-20 PSI and the pump motor is running but doesn't pump any water. I can open the points on the pressure switch and let them close and the pump will pump water and operate perfectly. I can also turn the house breaker off and then back on and the pump pumps water again. I have replaced the tank, pressure switch, pressure gage, check valve and the breaker in the house and it continues to do this frequently. It doesn't do it every time but does do it frequently. I initially had pressure set at 40-60 PSI and decreased it to 30-50 PSI. I have the air in bladder tank set at 2 PSI below the kick on pressure. I would appreciate any advice you might provide and may need someone to come and check it out. I had pump all of the down pipe replaced about 10-15 years ago due to a hole rusting in a couple of them. I have 100 feet of down pipe.

Comment: Please fell free to [edit] your post to include some line breaks to help organize your thoughts. The more clearly you communicate up front, the more quickly we'll be able to provide you some help.

Comment: How do you know the pump is pumping? Are you measuring the current? How many wire pump or is there a control box it sounds a lot like a bad start cap but that’s a guess at this point.

Answer (score 1):

The usual reason if all the rest of the bits are right is lack of water in the well.

If you have a "burnout preventer" or "pump-protector" pressure switch, those shut the pump off (while the control handle is in the "on" position) if it falls below 20 PSI, and while it's off, water will be flowing into the well at whatever your present recharge rate is, so it may indeed work when next turned on.

You can also try **lowering** the tank pre-charge pressure a bit **more** - sometimes if the pump does not spool up fast enough the buffer provided by the 2psi difference is not enough water. Easy to check - just change it to 3, 4, or 5 PSI and see if the problem goes away. If so you can either leave it there or add more tank capacity.